# What is the equivalent of a C# object variable in Java?

Tags: java, c#

I have this C# code:

```
var invoice = new {
       code = "01",
       otherThings = "etc",
       ...
  }
```

What would be the equivalent of this in Java?

I tried creating a: `Object[] invoice =  new Object[]{}` but don't know how to fill the object.

I hope I was clear enough, thanks.

Comment: `var invoice = new Object() { String code = "01", otherThings = "etc";}` Works, but it's a bad style. (Or is it?)

Comment: I hope we get such a feature with records, maybe as anonymous records, that just works. The example above doesn't implement hashCode, equals and toString. Would be nice through.

Comment: Thanks @JohannesKuhn but when using var I got a `Cannot resolve symbol var` error, and a `; expected` at the end of the brackets. I had to put it like: `Object invoice = new Object() { String code = "01", otherThings = "etc"; };` Is that correct?

Comment: `var` is a Java 10 feature.

Comment: Actually I downloaded the sdk of Java 10 and change te language level to ten but stll not working :(

Comment: JDK 10 is already out of date. Use Java 11 or 13.

Comment: Same result with Java 11.

Comment: Please post your java code so people can help you with it.

Comment: "not working" is not very informative (code snippet works fine with `jshell`; if compiling, must go inside a method that goes inside a class and be ended by a `;`) {{but not very usable, no access to fields/methods from outside the instance}}

Comment: Note that `var` is for _local variables only_ and will not work for class fields or method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like that:

```
Invoice i = new Invoice(){...};
```

But thats not Clean Code.

just write a constructor with all properties like:

```
public invoice(String code, String otherThings)
{
     this.code = code;
     this.otherThings = otherThings;
}
```

...

```
Invoice i = new Invoice("asdfasdf", "asdfasdf");

Oject[] invoice = new Object[5];
invoice[0] = (Object)i;
```